# How to know if whether "Hide spelling and grammar errors" is turned on in PowerPoint by C#/VBA?

Tags: c#, vba, powerpoint, office-interop

I want to know if whether the option "Hide spelling and grammar errors" is turned on or off (by C# or VBA). I found out the solution in Word, but in PowerPoint I can't find out the solution. Anyone can help me?
Thanks so much. Sorry if my English is not good.

```
bool HideSpellingErrors() //in Word
{
    GetActiveWordFile();                  
    if (_activeDoc.ShowSpellingErrors == false)
    return true;
    else return false;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try the same code?  I think activepresentation?

Comment: Press F2 to bring up the *Object Browser*, then search for "spell" and see what comes up under the PowerPoint library?

Comment: *Object Browser* is Ctrl+Alt+J in Visual Studio (F2 is for the VBE).

Comment: Sorry, not all commands are in the object model. None of the ones in the dialog are included.

Comment: I tried all the ways you said, but it's not work

Answer (score 2):

Office applications store their settings in a windows registry. For example, see [disable proofing, spell checker, using GPO](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f1e95b7e-3eca-4048-9d11-10e1249758a7/disable-proofing-spell-checker-using-gpo?forum=officeitproprevious).

You can try to use the [Process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) application to track what changes are required to disable or enable a particular setting in PowerPoint. See [How to Use Process Monitor to Track Registry and File System Changes](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/process-monitor-track-events-generate-log-file/) for more information.